# How to handle expired routes / sessions in express?

Tags: node.js, session, express, routes

I have my Express app setup using Passport for authorization. When a new user signs up, I want to do an email verification. So, after the user posts credentials, the /signup route gets the request and with success redirects to /sendmail for verification.

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/sendmail', 
    failureRedirect : '/signup'
}));
```

Also, to prevent unauthorized session, within the /signup route, the user is logged out and the session is destroyed.

```
app.get('/sendmail', function(req, res) {
    res.render('mailsent.ejs', { 
        message: 'An email with verification link has been sent to ' +  req.user.email + '. Please follow the link in your mail to verify your account before logging in.'
    });
    /* From keeping user authenticated after signup (not verfied yet)*/
    req.logOut(); 
    req.session.destroy();
    }
});
```

My question is, as the session is already destroyed, browser gets nothing back when the end-user refreshes the browser, or directly accesses the /sendmail route. How to prevent this. In other words, in the app.get('/sendmail') route, how would I check if the session is on(valid req object) else redirect to '/'.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a middleware route like so:

```
app.use('/sendmail', function(req, res, next) { // Middleware for only the `/sendmail` route
    if (req.session.authenticated) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
    }
});
```

Or just put it right into your route:

```
app.get('/sendmail', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.session.authenticated) {
       return res.redirect("/"); // Redirect to home page if not authenticated
    }
    res.render('mailsent.ejs', { 
        message: 'An email with verification link has been sent to ' +  req.user.email + '. Please follow the link in your mail to verify your account before logging in.'
    });
    /* From keeping user authenticated after signup (not verfied yet)*/
    req.logOut(); 
    req.session.destroy();
    }
});
```

Comment: Here, req.session.authenticated is undefined and thus '/sendmail' just redirects to '/'

Comment: Well yeah, it was just an example, you need to set some sort of session variable to determine whether or not they should be authenticated or not. Replace `req.session.authenticated` with `req.session.email` if you want, just anything that should be set at the time of them being authenticated

Comment: Well, `req.session` always returns false. However `req.user` worked for me. I am testing out the MEAN stack and so far I like it. Thanks.